# Error 'inserted value too large for column' while altering a table to add default value

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I am trying to alter a table to add a default value for the column REFERENCE_NO  (VARCHAR2(40)) in a table (Oracle 11g) using the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME  MODIFY REFERENCE_NO DEFAULT (TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYDDD')))||'IW'||LPAD(TO_CHAR("SEQ_CG_IW_REF_NO"."NEXTVAL"),9,'0'));
```

When I execute the above statement, I get the following error: "ORA-01401: inserted value too large for column". But, irrespective of the sequence result, the value should have been maximum of 16 characters length because of the LPAD and the REFERENCE_NO is of VARCHAR2(40) type.

However, when I am querying using the following statement:

```
select (TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYDDD')))||'IW'||LPAD(TO_CHAR("SEQ_CG_IW_REF_NO"."NEXTVAL"),9,'0'))from dual;
```

The result of the query is '18031IW000010008' which is also of length 16 caharacters. Hence, I am unable to find why the alter command is failing even though the default value is of length 16 and the column length is 40. Thanks in advance
`

Answer (score -1):

By default a VARCHAR2(35) is VARCHAR2(35 BYTE) rather than VARCHAR2(35 CHAR).

This definition means that the column has byte length semantics which means the max length is 35 bytes.

In a multi-byte character set this is unlikely to be appropriate as a 35 char column might have several times the number of bytes.

Go through below article, 
https://community.oracle.com/thread/3730347?start=0&tstart=0